# Multiple Interfaces but only one (eth0) works

Tags: routes, ip, private-subnet

I have three interfaces ( 2 ethernet and 1 Wifi), as shown in below table. eth0 (192.168.1.62) is connected to WLAN router (192.168.1.1) and wl1 (192.168.1.114) is also connected to same router via wifi dongle.

But I cannot ping or access 192.168.1.1 via wl1 once eth0 and eth1 is up. what should I do to get access same time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

applications must use route to specefied local network (192.168.1.0/24) with minimum Metric value (0) - interface eth0.

Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.